# Capacity schedular is able to submit jobs in other queues, inspite on correct config setting

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

Below is my scheduler xml file, i  restricted access to root queues, where as dev2, qa2 users should submit to their queues only. But i can submit jobs to QA queue as dev2 user also, this should not happen , I have also modified accordingly in RANGER YARN policies & disabled super policy that had all queues access to all users, please advice me .

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor=1
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state=RUNNING
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity=40
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity=40
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications= 
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_jobs= 
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.capacity=100
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_administer_queue= 
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels=*
yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay=40
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications=10000
yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=0.2
yarn.scheduler.capacity.default.minimum-user-limit-percent=100
capacity-scheduler=null
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues=dev,qa,default
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_administer_jobs= 
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_queue= 
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit=1
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.dev.acl_submit_applications=dev2
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.dev.capacity=30
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.dev.maximum-capacity=30
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.dev.user-limit=1
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.qa.acl_submit_applications=qa2
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.qa.capacity=30
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.qa.maximum-capacity=30
yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.qa.user-limit=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing out the property that blocks access to `root` queue.

Here `root` is the parent queue for both `dev` and `qa` child queues. The access to this queue is not restricted, thus all users and groups and have access to this queue and to its child queues.

Add this property to the `capacity-scheduler.xml`,

```
  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value> </value>
  </property>
```

This blocks access to `root` queue to all users and groups, then the acls provided for the child queues will be restrictive as defined.